# WPF PropertyGrid supports multiple selection

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, wpf-extended-toolkit

Is this documentation still valid or am I missing something?

http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid~SelectedObjects.html

`PropertyGrid` control does not appear to have `SelectedObjects` or `SelectedObjectsOverride` members. I'm using the latest version (2.5) of the Toolkit against .NET Framework 4.0.

### UPDATE

@faztp12's answer got me through. For anyone else looking for a solution, follow these steps:

1. Bind your `PropertyGrid`'s `SelectedObject` property to the first selected item. Something like this:

   ```
   <xctk:PropertyGrid PropertyValueChanged="PG_PropertyValueChanged" SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedObjects[0]}"  />
   ```
2. Listen to `PropertyValueChanged` event of the `PropertyGrid` and use the following code to update property value to all selected objects.

   ```
   private void PG_PropertyValueChanged(object sender, PropertyGrid.PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     var changedProperty = (PropertyItem)e.OriginalSource;

     foreach (var x in SelectedObjects) {
       //make sure that x supports this property
       var ProperProperty = x.GetType().GetProperty(changedProperty.PropertyDescriptor.Name);

       if (ProperProperty != null) {

         //fetch property descriptor from the actual declaring type, otherwise setter 
         //will throw exception (happens when u have parent/child classes)
         var DeclaredProperty = ProperProperty.DeclaringType.GetProperty(changedProperty.PropertyDescriptor.Name);

         DeclaredProperty.SetValue(x, e.NewValue);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: Im having the same version `2.5` and `SelectedObjects` isnt there in `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid`

Comment: @faztp12 Seems to be in Plus version only.

Comment: @faztp12  See [Show common properties of multiple objects](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid-Plus#user-content-propertygrid-plus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did when i had similar problem was I subscribed to `PropertyValueChanged` and had a `List` filled myself with the `SelectedObjects`.

I checked if the contents of the List where of the same type, and then if it is so, I changed the property in each of those item :

```
PropertyItem changedProperty = (PropertyItem)e.OriginalSource;
PropertyInfo t = typeof(myClass).GetProperty(changedProperty.PropertyDescriptor.Name);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    foreach (myClass x in SelectedItems)
                        t.SetValue(x, e.NewValue);
                }
```

I used this because i needed to make a Layout Designer and this enabled me change multiple item's property together :)

Hope it helped :)

Ref [Xceed Docs](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid~PropertyValueChanged_EV.html)

Comment: Interesting. What is `changeProperty`?

Comment: It is the parameter that comes in with the event `PropertyValueChanged` :)

Comment: I don't see any such parameter in `PropertyValueChanged` event. Are you sure you're using the `PropertyGrid` control from Extended WPF Tookit?

Comment: oops, sorry :P edited the answer with the `changedProperty` :)

Comment: Very helpful indeed. This finally got me thru. Thanks a bunch. There is one more thing i had to do. See my edit.