# Writing a properties aggregator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection

**Background**

After spending a lot of time researching, I have not found any way of assigning multiple objects to `PropertyGrid` (Extended WPF Toolkit). My next idea is to create my own aggregator class that takes in selected objects and exposes their **common** properties to the outside world. I'll then assign (an instance of) this class to `PropertyGrid`. Any changes made by the user in `PropertyGrid` will be passed on to the selected objects by the aggregator class.

**Question**

Is there anything in the Framework (especially **Reflection**) that could help me with this task? All objects in my domain inherit from a common ancestor and add new properties of their own (or override ancestor versions). Class hierarchy is multiple levels deep.

### UPDATE

For anyone else stuck in the same situation as me, I was able to finally solve `PropertyGrid` problem. See [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010077/wpf-propertygrid-supports-multiple-selection) for the solution.

Comment: With what you want, you need to create the aggregator class ***dynamically*** . So it's hard to be done easily (we need to use `System.Reflection.Emit`). In fact it may be easier if we generate the class definition code and use `System.CodeDom.Compiler` and `Microsoft.CSharp`. I wonder why  you want to do something like that? If you want to show all common properties in the `PropertyGrid`, I guess you can set its `SelectedObjects` (instead of just `SelectedObject`) to your array of objects.

Comment: Well, I've just realized you mean the `PropertyGrid` in extended toolkit, looks like it does not support multiple objects selection.

Comment: @Hopeless: Your ID frightens me more than your answer!

Comment: I guess the solution to your problem will even make you more frighten than my ID.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I can interpret what you want correctly.

One of the idea is using T4ToolBox to generate pre-compile class by scripting (which is also C# code in a template file).

- Define your objects that want to be aggregate into xml.
- Then you can use reflection to loop through all public method/properties in the objects (based on the xml) to find out the set of common methods
- Generate an interface and (if you want) the corresponding concrete classes
- One manual work after this is change your original object by implementing the newly generated interface.